# Separar número con puntos usando sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Hola tengo un archivo con un numero relacionado con la versión de un programa, por ejemplo `v1.0.0`.

Tengo que operar con él, por lo que he eliminado la `v` y los puntos. Lo he redirigido a otro archivo, de manera que `v1.0.0` pasa a ser `100`.

Ahora necesito volver a añadir la `v` y un punto por cada cifra, es decir si por ejemplo tengo el `101` necesito que sea `v1.0.1`.

¿Alguna manera sobre como hacerlo?

Comment: Prueba con esto: `echo 101 | sed -e 's/./\.&/g' -e 's/^./v/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más apropiado como dices es usar `sed`. Depende de cómo vayas 'a operar' con el archivo o el dato el comando variaría. La llamada a `sed` sería `sed -e 's/./\.&/g' -e 's/^./v/g'`.

Si estás usando tuberías, tal y como indica @masterguru sería:

```bash
echo 101 | sed -e 's/./\.&/g' -e 's/^./v/g'
```

Si el contenido está en un archivo, puedes redirigirlo:

```bash
sed -e 's/./\.&/g' -e 's/^./v/g' < file
```

Comment: Sería mejor respuesta si explicaras como operan esas expresiones regulares en `sed`